# When is "ei" a diphthong?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, vowel, diphthong

Many introductory Latin books will explain that Classical Latin has four diphthongs: *ae* and *au* are common, while *oe* and *ei* are rarer. (*Eu* and *ui* also show up, but if I understand right that's a Greek influence that doesn't appear in native words.)

However, it's hard for me to think of *any* common Latin words with an *ei* diphthong. For example, the pronoun *eī* is pronounced with two syllables, and *ē-iciō* "to throw out" with three.

Cassel's dictionary lists *dē-inde* as an example of the diphthong. But how can I, as a non-native speaker, keep track of which is which? Both *dē-inde* and *ē-iciō* have a long *ē*, a short *i*, and a morpheme boundary in the middle. Why does one have a diphthong and the other not? Is there a rule I can learn for this?

(P.S. Does anyone write the diphthong as *ej* and the hiatus as *ei*? That would be really convenient.)

(P.P.S. *Oe* mostly shows up in Greek words, but is also found in some nice native Latin roots, like *foedus* "treaty".)

Comment: Would you classify *huius* and *cuius* as Greek influence?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Huh, are those pronounced with a diphthong? I always said them `/hu.jus/` and `/ku.jus/`, with a syllable break in between. (Similarly `/e.jus/` and `/pe.jus/`.)

Comment: The first syllables of all of them are heavy by metric evidence and I don't think any of the vowels are long. The J is regularly geminated between vowels and there is no big difference between /kuj.jus/ and /kui.jus/, so I would certainly see it as a diphthong *ui*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Interesting; I'll have to ask another question about that later

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Question asked [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/9313/406); feel free to post an answer!

Comment: If diphthongs that can have a separate digraph were written as such, it would indeed be much easier. J could replace I where you have /i̯a/, /i̯e/, /i̯o/, /i̯u/, your suggestion ej I do like, and æ could replace ae for /a̯e/ and œ could replace oe for /o̯e/, ui could be the monophthong whereas vi the diphthong. It is not perfect, but I believe it could be quite helpful.

Comment: Seu is a native word

Comment: Not really relevant, but still interesting: Norwegian has a single word (with derivatives) which contains the diphthong _ui_ /ʉɪ/: ‘hui’ (noun (m and n) and interjection) and its verbal origin ‘huie’ (the nouns and interjection are derivatives of the verb, not the other way around). The origin of the word is Germanic, ɔ: Low German. Could it be that few instances of a phoneme is indicative of a loan-word origin?

Comment: @pápilió Vērē! Forcellini: «**SEU.** Coniunctio disiunctiva, per contractionem a _sive_, ut _neu_ a _neve_» Et _neu_: «**NĒVE**  et _per apocopen_ Neu. Coniunctio disiunctiva a _ne_, particula negativa, et _ve_, quod pro _vel_ dicitur.»

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very few Latin words contain "ei" as a diphthong. Some possible examples are *deinde, dein, deinceps, rei, spei,* and in fact, the pronoun *ei* (but not always).

The exact list of examples depends on what you call a "diphthong" (e.g. whether you include words with intervocalic geminate semivowels, or words where the vowels are pronounced in one syllable because of "synizesis").

Old Latin had a diphthong *ei* (original *ai* and *oi* turned into it when they were in non-initial syllables), but because of sound changes, words that had *ei* in Old Latin ended up being pronounced in Classical Latin with /iː/, the same sound as the reflex of Old Latin long i. (In some cases, *ei* instead merged with *e*.)

Because of that sound change, the digraph <ei> after the Old Latin period was used as a spelling of the monophthong /iː/, not only in cases where /iː/ etymologically originated from a diphthong (as in the second declension masculine nominative plural), but also in some cases where /iː/ etymologically originated from a long monophthong.

This historical sound change and the resulting spelling convention where <ei> = /iː/ creates some additional difficulty with determining the pronunciation of Latin word forms spelled with <ei>.

### Before a consonant: *deinde* and friends

Cser (2016) argues that Latin has no genuine diphthongs, only vowel + glide sequences. Cser says that, if we set aside words with geminate /j.j/, /ej/ occurs in the following three related words: *deinde, dein, deinceps* (p. 32). As far as I know, these are never written with <ej>. L&S says that *[dehinc](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddehinc)* is frequently a monosyllable in poetry, which could be interpreted as implying a pronunciation /dejnk/.

Scansion alone doesn't tell us the exact pronunciation of <ei> here. I'm not sure what basis Cser and other scholars have to state that these words had /ej/ specifically, as opposed to some other monosyllabic sound like /eː/, /iː/, or even /e/ or /i/ (with the syllable being heavy because of coda /n/).

Some sources seem to categorize the disyllabic pronunciation of *deinde* and/or *dehinc* as an example of synizesis, alongside e.g. the pronunciation of "eo" in one syllable in words like *alveo.* Synizesis is also supposed to be possible in the word *proin* (pro͡in = [projn]?), a shortened version of the similarly formed *proinde.*

Adams (2016) gives *dende* as a 2nd-century spelling of *deinde* (Chapter 22, "Letter of Claudius Terentianus (*P. MICH.* VIII.471, *CEL* 146), of the Early Second Century"; the text is sourced from Kramer 2007).

In the notes, Adams says that "the phonetics [of "synezesis" in *deinde*] tend not to be addressed", and that "it remains unclear in what way (or ways) the term was pronounced in the early period; for the scansion *dĕīnde* in Terence see Questa (2007: 439)."

Adams suggests that a form with ē developed eventually in Latin, bringing up  *cōgo* from *co-* + *ago* as an example of a contraction resulting in a long vowel with quality of the first component. As evidence against reading the first syllable of <dende> as [dɛn], Adams brings up (obsolete) reflexes in Spanish and Portuguese with forms like *dende*: these point towards Proto-Western-Romance *e rather than *ɛ, because *ɛ would lead to the form **diende* [djende], which is apparently not attested ("information from Adam Ledgeway"). Adams says the same would go for Spanish *dentro* (not **dientro*) from Latin *de-* + *intro.*

Adams doesn't seem to mention that Proto-Western-Romance *e corresponds not only to Latin ē, but also to Latin ĭ, which I think is relevant because *de* + *ĭ* > *dĭ* seems like a plausible alternative kind of contraction.

### Word-final [ej] (sometimes?): *ei*; *rei, spei*; *Pompei*

There are a few situations where word-final [ej] may have occurred, but I have the impression that it was often in variation with disyllabic sequences, rather than the only pronunciation used.

#### dative *ei*

The pronunciation of *ei*, the dative form of *is,* is a complicated question, but there seem to be cases where it must scan as one syllable (Weiss 2010).

In the cases where it does so scan, it seems likely that the pronunciation was /ej/, which would be favored both by intra-paradigmatic analogy with the genitive singular /ejjus/ and inter-paradigmatic analogy with the datives *cui* and *huic,* whose monosyllabic pronunciations are currently widely interpreted as having been /kuj/ and /hujk/, containing falling diphthongs or /j/-offglides.

#### fifth declension *rei, spei*

Genitive and dative singular forms of the fifth declension can end in <ei>. The use and pronunciation of these forms is complicated by the existence of a lot of variation in this area; the fifth declension was the smallest Latin noun declension and was subject to various pressures of (attempted) regularization or of analogy with the first declension.

Per Lindsay (1896),

> [Because the fifth declension followed the pattern of the first, we should expect] to find find a disyllabic *-ēī*, which through the working of Latin phonetic laws would become *-ĕī*, and in rapid utterance even *-e͡i* (class *-ī*) in the genitive, but a diphthongal -ei which would become either *-ē* or *-e͡i* (class. Lat. *-ī*) in the dative.

(page 425)

In other words, based on what Lindsay writes, a historical [ej] in these forms should be expected to have developed to a monophthong *-ē* or *-ī.*

Exon (1905), who cites Lindsay (1896) along with Seyffert, specifies that in early Latin, the monosyllabic *ei* at the end of dative fifth declension nouns can undergo elision, while the *ei* at the end of genitive fifth declension nouns cannot: he argues that this implies that the dative ended in a monophthong intermediate between /iː/ and /eː/ (in Exon's notation, "ẹ̄", which in modern IPA would be /e̝ː/; this is standardly reconstructed as an intermediate step in the shift from Old Latin *ei* to /iː/~/eː/), whereas the monosyllabic genitive ending *ei* was an actual phonetic diphthong /ej/ (pages 556-557). Then at a "comparatively late" stage, the disyllabic dative ending came into use.

I don't know how the situation evolved past then, but I think it's possible that some classical Latin speakers ended up using [ej] in either the genitive or the dative based on later compression/synizesis of disyllabic eī or ēī.

#### genitive *Pompei* (usually trisyllabic)

It seems that the vocative form *Pompei* was most commonly pronounced with three heavy syllables (for which see below), but some sources indicate that it also had a pronounciation with two syllables.  Allen 1890 cites Horace *Carmina* II. 7.5:

> Pompe͡i meorum prime sodalium.

(page 75)

(This is the first line of an Alcaic stanza, and thus should scan as – – u – – | – u u – u –).

In contrast, Exon 1905 denies knowing any examples of Pompe͡i (page 560).

Priscian writes about this name, but Allen and Exon disagree about what he says.

### Before a vowel: /ej.j/

Latin had a number of words where an intervocalic letter <i>  represented /j.j/, a geminate palatal approximant/glide/semivowel. It is inferred that these words had a geminate consonant based on the existence of some older spellings with double <ii>, the heavy weight of the syllable preceding the intervocalic <i>, and the development in Romance languages, such as the geminate affricate in Italian *maggiore* from Latin *maiorem.* These words have modern spelling variants with  <j>.

The geminate palatal approximant /j.j/ could occur after /e/, as in the word *eius/ejus* mentioned in Joonas's answer.
I would not consider the /ej/ in /ej.jus/ to be a diphthong any more than the /ju/ is.

Some sources, particularly older dictionaries like L&S, may write this as *ēi* or *ēj*, where the macron represents syllable weight but does not necessarily represent the true length of the vowel itself.

Some instances of <ei> are thought to have been pronounced /ej.ji/. Cser mentions *reicere* (p. 149) and the genitive form *Pompei* (p. 13).

There are some prefixed words where, based on etymology, we would expect /eː.j/, although metrically there's no way of distinguishing this from /ej.j/. You mentioned *eicio,* which is thought to have started with /eː.ji/; another word that is thought to have had /eː.j/ is *seiungo.*

(For more discussion of pronunciations like /ji/, /j.ji/, or /j.j/ for <i> in contexts other than just <ei>, see my answer to [When is an I not an I?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/91/9)).

### other /ej/ before a consonant?

There might be a few other examples of /ej/ before a consonant, but it's not necessarily clear. Cser brings it up as a potential pronunciation of <ei> in "anteis", "anteit" and "anteire" but suggests that /iː/ is a more likely pronunciation in this word (p. 150).

### Works Cited

- Allen, Frederic D. 1890. "[Gajus or Gaïus?](https://books.google.com/books?id=6108AAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA75&lpg=RA1-PA75&dq=vocative+%22Pompei)". *Harvard Studies in Classical Philology,* Volumes 1-2.
- Lindsay, W. M. December 1896. "The Dative Singular of the Fifth Declension in Latin." *The Classical Review,* Vol. 10, No. 9, pp. 424-427.
- Exon, Charles. 1905. "[The Latin Genitive in *-ai.*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23036869)" *Hermathena*
  Vol. 13, No. 31, pp. 555-574.
- Weiss, Michael. 21 September 2010. "[The Scansion of dat. sg. ei in Classical Latin](http://ohcgl.blogspot.com/2010/09/scansion-of-dat-sg-ei-in-classical.html)", *OHCGL Addenda and Corrigenda* (blog).
- Adams, J. N. 2016. *[An Anthology of Informal Latin, 200 BC–AD 900: Fifty Texts with Translations and Linguistic Commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=UIMHDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT392).*
- Cser, András. 2016. "[Aspects of the Phonology and Morphology of Classical Latin](http://real-d.mtak.hu/896/7/dc_1106_15_doktori_mu.pdf)."

Answer (score 6):

The diphthong *ei* is found before vowels: *eius*, *peior*.
The intervocalic *i* is typically geminated (see [this question about I and J](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14/79)) so that *eius* is pronounced like /ej.jus/ which is practically the same as /ei.jus/.
I find it most reasonable to see this *ei* as a diphthong.
I am not aware of occurrences before a consonant.

This is quite similar to *ui* appearing in *cuius* and *huius*.
It also appears in *cui*.
If you are unconvinced that it should not be *cuī* instead, see for example [the occurrences in the Aeneid](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=cui%23+%5Bverg%3Aa%5D), including the very first syllable of a number of verses.

In an answer to the ["Oh no!" question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/9303/79) luchonacho mentioned the interjection [*ei*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dei2).
Judging by this line in Ovid's *Amores*, it is a single diphthong unlike the pronoun(s) *ei*:

> *Ei mihi, quod dominam nec vir nec femina servas*

Answer (score 3):

In Horatius, Satires, I, 6 :
"Deinde eo dormitum, non sollicitus mihi quod cras", the "ei" in "deinde" seems to be a diphtong if my scansion is right?